# Отследить ошибку в php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

Привет всем! В error логе php-fpm периодически вылетает ошибка. Есть ли способ понять какой запрос её спровоцировал? У access лога есть формат, который может задавать пользователь. Но у error лога формата не нахожу. Как тогда отследить ошибку?

Comment: в `error_log` пишеться фаил в котором произошла ошибка.

Comment: А как узнать какой запрос к вебсерверу вызвал обращение к этому файлу?

Comment: Обычно fpm дублирует ошибки в stderr, так что посмотрите в error log nginx'а. Дефолтно nginx пишет контекст запроса, на который ему что-то вернули в stderr вместе с самим stderr.